# Magento 2.2: How to redirect to category page?

Tags: magento2, redirect

I am trying to return a resultRedirect with the category URL but it always redirects me to the current page.

What is the correct way to do it?

```
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryId);
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    return $resultRedirect->setUrl($category->getUr());
```

Comment: From where you are trying this above code?

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your module to set redirect.

```
protected $resultRedirect;

public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory $result){
   $this->resultRedirect = $result;
}

public function execute()
{
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirect->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
    $resultRedirect->setUrl('url to redirect');

    return $resultRedirect;         
 }
```

Hope it helps!!!